# Windows: how to enable tags on old image files?

Tags: windows, metadata, jpeg, tags, exif

I have a lot of old photos which I want to tag. For cross-platform compatibility, I want to use IPTC Keywords for tagging. As far as I read, the native Windows photo tagging capabilities use IPTC Keywords for the tags.

Problem is, on most of my pictures, the "Tags" property does not show up in the details pane, and if I display `Properties-> Details` of the image, the 'Tags' section is not editable.

If I copy the file, the tagging will be enabled on the copy and work. My guess is that the original files contain only old EXIF but not IPTC metadata and that by copying windows does add the IPTC metadata automatically. Now I could go and copy around all my pictures - but maybe there's an easier way to enable the tagging on the existing files?

[image: tagging only works on the copy of the image]

Comment: Are not your files read-only?

Comment: No, checked that

Comment: How about file permissions? Does them allows to edit files?

Comment: how/where do I check those? If i rightlick on the image and check the properties, "Read-only" and "hidden" are both not selected. in the 'Advanced...' panel the file attributes "File is ready for archiving" and "Allow this file to have contents indexed in addition to file properties" both are enabled and the 'Compress or Encrypt attributes' are disabled

Comment: Check "Security" tab of file properties. Or try to edit file, can you save it?